# Check value in Radio Button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

FORM :

```html
<form id="approvalPenambahanUserInt" name="approvalPenambahanUserInt" action="" method="post">

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <label for="persetujuan" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Status</label>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input type="radio" name="persetujuan" id="Approved" class="logintStatuses" value="1">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Disetujui
        <input type="radio" name="persetujuan" id="Rejected" class="logintStatuses" value="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Ditolak
      </div>
</form>
```

and I try this is not working.

JS :

```js
$("#approvalPenambahanUserInt").submit(function(e) {
  let form = $(this);
    if ($('input[name="persetujuan"]:checked').length === 0){
    alert('Please Choose Status!');
    return false;
  }else if($('input[name="persetujuan"]:checked').length === 1){
    alert('Accepted!');
  }else {
    alert('Rejected!');}
});
```

can someone help i try to find if value 1 = Accepted and 2 is rejected

Comment: $('input[name="persetujuan"]) .value ===  "1"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
document.forms.approvalPenambahanUserInt
  .addEventListener('submit', function(event)
  {
  event.preventDefault() // disable submit
  console.clear()
  if (!this.persetujuan.value)
    {
    console.log('Please Choose Status!')
    }
  else
    {
    console.log( this.persetujuan.value )
    }
  })
```

```html
<form  name="approvalPenambahanUserInt" action="" method="post">

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Status</label>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="persetujuan" value="Approved" class="logintStatuses" >
          Disetujui
        </label>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="persetujuan" value="Rejected" class="logintStatuses" >
          Ditolak
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you shold check this [radio button jquery](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/tCXgg/3/)

Main issue is `let form = $(this);` this line, I am sure when you using `$(this)` you are assuming it is form object but when you use this in javascript this should return window object.